# Adding mini-login to header of page

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I want to add a user login option to the header of my website with [this](http://magentostriker.blogspot.ie/2012/02/use-mini-login-in-header-or-anywhere.html)

I have added

```
<block type="customer/form_login" name="mini_login" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml" />
```

to the `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml` file and

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mini_login') ?>
```

to the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml` file, but nothing appears. I did add `Hello` after `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mini_login') ?>` and `Hello` does appear. I did clear the cache storage, but it still doesn't appear.

Why is the login not showing?

Comment: you should edit app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout/page.xml and app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/page/html/header.phtml Not just base/default

Comment: In the `frontend` directory there is only `base` and `default`. If I go into `default` then there is only `etc` and `locale`?

Comment: @PavelNovitsky If I make any other changes to that `page.xml` and it has showed up correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

goto `customer.xml`(path app/design/frontend/your package/your template/layout)  add below tag under `<default></default>` default tag

```
<default>
....
    <reference name="header">
                <block type="customer/form_login" name="header_customer_form_mini_login"  template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"/>
        </reference>
...
</default>
```

Under call this file under `header.phtml` using this code `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header_customer_form_mini_login');?>`